# Convergence of sum of alternating functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n:[-1,1]\to[0,1]$ be continuous functions. Assume that for every $x\in [-1,1]$, $\{f_n(x)\}$ is decreasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$. Let $g_n(x)=\sum_{m=1}^{n}(-1)^mf_m(x)$. Show that $\{g_n(x)\}$ converges to some $g(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. In particular, show that $g$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$.

If we can show $\{g_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g$, then we are done, right? However due to the way this problem is phrased, I think it's hard to directly show uniform convergence. But even if we can show point-wise convergence first, since $\{g_n\}$ aren't monotonic, we can't use Dini's theorem to claim $g$ is continuous.

Please help!

Comment: The alternating series test, and more generally Dirichlet's test, applies to uniform convergence as well. So, once you know from Dini's theorem that $f_n \searrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$, then you can apply the alternating test to conclude that $\sum_n g_n$ converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted my first proof because it required some extra work.

Simply follow the proof of the alternating series theorem in baby Rudin. The fact that $f_n$ decreases to $0$ uniformly will tell you that the series is uniformly convergent (by the same proof). [$f_n$ decreases to $0$ uniformly by Dini's Theorem].

Comment: Wait, you meant $g_{2n}$ is decreasing? $g(2n+2)-g(2n)=g(2n+2)-g(2n+1)\leq 0$ right?

Comment: @FluffySkye Yes, sorry!

Comment: Ok, so by alternating series test we know the partial sums $g_n(x)$ converge and by Dini's theorem we know $g_{2n-1}$ and $g_{2n}$ individually converges to $g$.

Comment: Ummm, I'm confused. If we can divide a sequence of functions into several parts like we did here and if all of the parts are individually monotic, can we say the limit is continuous?

Comment: You have to use the fact that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly (by Dini's Theorem) and you also have to obtain bounds for the two monotonic sequences.

Comment: Why do we need boundedness? You meant that even though the alternating series converge, $g_{2n}$ and $g_{2n-1}$ might not converge?

Comment: @FluffySkye I have added an entirely new proof to my answer.